# Upgraded to Mountain Lion, now 127.0.0.1 is not resolving

Tags: osx-mountain-lion

I used to be able to type 127.0.0.1 (or my network IP 10.10.53.32) and it would resolve to my "default" virtual host. 127.0.0.1/~Shanimal and shanimal.dev both resolve to their appropriate folders. localhost and 127.0.0.1 give me a 404 - "**Not Found** The requested URL / was not found on this server."

Basically, my "It works!" screen no longer works.

**/private/etc/apache2/Shanimal.conf:**

```
<Directory "/Users/Shanimal/Sites/_www">
    Options Indexes Multiviews
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**hosts:**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 shanimal.dev
```

Comment: Does entering your public IP address still work as before?

Comment: What's the log output in `/var/log/apache2/error_log`? Access via Console.app or Terminal.

Comment: It's a 404 as well.

Comment: nothing seems to be appended there. i did a `tail - f /var/log/apache2/error_log`

Comment: Skip the space: `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log`. So, no output like `[Mon Oct 22 18:28:40 2012] [error] [client fe80::1] File does not exist: /Library/WebServer/Documents/foo`?

Comment: no there's stuff in there from before I switched to Mtn Lion

Comment: Daniel... I get a warning there [Mon Oct 22 09:25:45 2012] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the reference to the two dummy vhost examples in **/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf*** and this pretty much did the trick for me. Daniel put me on the right track by telling me where the logs were located (+1)

I had originally created the special user.conf file while following [these instructions](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57481978-263/how-to-enable-web-sharing-in-os-x-mountain-lion/).

Since I don't care about the /~Shanimal user folder, I removed **/private/etc/apache2/Shanimal.conf** and pointed the DocumentRoot to a symlink "_www" in my Sites folder.

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/Shanimal/Sites/_www"
<Directory "/Users/Shanimal/Sites/_www">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This configuration actually works with the dummy vhost entries removed (pointing to a wrong but valid place) so I suppose the dummy vhost entries were the problem. All is working as expected now.

Comment: Google searched, found this and it helped me again. a new machine with a fresh install Mtn Lion... Thanks Shanimal!